# Misalignment of facebook "like" button to the "tweet" and "pin" button

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, pinterest

I am not good with code so if someone could give me a straightforward easy answer it would be hugely appreciated! As this is such an annoying problem.

Thank you in advance
Jake

Comment: You should not link to your site as a question.  What happens when you site is fixed?  This question is useless.

Comment: see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/197460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is my solution :

Put your social buttons into a list like that :

```
<ul>
    <li>Facebook code</li>
    <li>Twitter code</li>
    <li>Pinterest code</li>
</ul>
```

In the css, add a style for li :

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

With the vertical alignement to the top, all your buttons will be aligned.

Comment: Thanks! Although it's only moved my pinterest and facebook button it's left the twitter button in the original place. - www.jakespruce.co.uk

Comment: Just put your h1 out of the li and it will work ;)

Comment: Aha! doh. Success cheers thank you.